# How to install applications in Sandbox?

Tags: system-installation

I am facing a problem using 10.04, I had installed **badgerports** on my system to run **mono** application and that was working fine but when I installed Wine on my system my mono applications does not work.

I think Wine had updated dependencies for badgerports, please someone suggest me on how to install applications isolated (in sandbox) to resolve dependencies conflict? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Wine should not interfere with any mono stuff, they are completely separed packages as far as I know. What may change upon wine installation are file association in the filemanager. If mono was the only option, all windows-like apps were executed through mono. 
After wine installation, that could be the default way to run win apps.
Right click on the exe you want to run and select "mono" from the "Open with..." menu.
It this still does not work, try executing the app from the terminal,

```
mono /path/to/app
```

And post here errors.

To install apps in sandbox I usually make use of schroot and debootstrap ([follow this Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot)). Use this as a last resort: it's better to understand why your system stopped working!